# MySQL 5.7 - Select JSON document as Table

Tags: json, mysql-5.7

I have a following JSON data format which has simple Key/Value pair data.

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (id INT, jdoc JSON);

INSERT INTO test_table VALUES 
  (1, '{"CS":15, "Physics":20,"Chemistry":10}'),
  (2, '{"CS":6, "Physics":8,"Chemistry":5}');
```

I need to select above data in following format. i.e. Key name (Key Name is dynamic) as column name and value as data.

```
id| CS | Physics | Chemistry
1 | 15 | 20      | 10
2 | 6  | 8       | 5
```

I got the following solution from senior SO member "Akina" using `JSON_TABLE`. But this function only supports in MySQL 8.0

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69673530/1791406

Is there any alternatives of `JSON_TABLE` function in MySQL 5.7. Or get any clue to get the required results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the old fashioned way, using json_extract and paths:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=403c4a6fa81b514214d3f10ddb4cf50e

```
SELECT t.id, 
  t.jdoc->'$.CS' as CS, 
  t.jdoc->'$.Physics' as Physics, 
  t.jdoc->'$.Chemistry' as Chemistry
FROM test_table t
```

Where -> is a shorthand operator for json_extract.  Depending on the format of the data you are getting out, you may need to use ->> which is the shorthand operator for json_unquote(json_extract()).

You can support unknown keys by building dynamic paths, but it becomes less readable:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=bb9bf699ace41e6dd0e475e60b60605b

```
SELECT t.id, 
  json_extract(t.jdoc, concat('$.', json_extract(json_keys(t.jdoc), '$[0]'))) as k0,
  json_extract(t.jdoc, concat('$.', json_extract(json_keys(t.jdoc), '$[1]'))) as k1,
  json_extract(t.jdoc, concat('$.', json_extract(json_keys(t.jdoc), '$[2]'))) as k2
FROM test_table t;
```

You can see that the outputs are identical, except for the column names.  If the column names are important, you can use a prepared statement to dynamically generate the query with field names, then prepare a statement from that and execute it.  See this fiddle:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fb2ab27407789bdfad04e0a53d9a0257

```
SELECT json_keys(t.jdoc) INTO @keys FROM test_table t LIMIT 1;
SET @query = CONCAT("SELECT t.id, "
"t.jdoc->'$.", json_extract(@keys, '$[0]'), "' as ", json_extract(@keys, '$[0]'), ", ",
"t.jdoc->'$.", json_extract(@keys, '$[1]'), "' as ", json_extract(@keys, '$[1]'), ", ",
"t.jdoc->'$.", json_extract(@keys, '$[2]'), "' as ", json_extract(@keys, '$[2]'),
"FROM test_table t;");

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Readability goes straight out the window, and maintaining will be a real chore.  I believe variables are deprecated, so there's no telling how long it will work, and it's generally recommended to avoid running dynamically generated sql.  But it will generate the desired result.

Bear in mind that executing dynamically generated sql opens you up to many possible harms.  You are essentially taking text from somewhere else and then executing it on your system.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but the Key names are not known in jdoc but the format is.

Comment: Sure.  So you will just need to get the 1st value, the 2nd value and the 3rd value, regardless of key names?

Comment: @Zeeshanef check the edit.  Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: it is a great solution, but can we show key name as column name instead of k0, k1 and k2. i.e. k0={key name} which is CS, k=1=Physics ands so on.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't through with my edit when you left that comment.  Yes, it is possible and I was in the middle of adding the capability.  Check now.

Comment: Thanks your third solution worked for me. Can we improve it to get nth keys instead of hardcoded 3 columns. e.g. currently if we have 4th key in JSON document so we would require to CONCAT another line with index [3] and so on. Regards,

Comment: It's a proof of concept, so you can of course institute any kind of logic in construction of the query.